# High average load + low cpu usage + low disk usage + normal network usage + normal memory usage = ok or not?

Tags: linux, networking, cpu, performance, cpu-load

I see high CPU average load several times a day on my server. For example, 21:20 and 22:45 on the following figure:

[image]

However, my CPU, disk, and network are all OK:

1. Disk

[image]

2. Network

[image]

3. CPU

[image]

[image]

4. Memory

[image]

5. Also do not see strange forks

[image]

[image]

6. Interrupts also ok

[image]

I have read through many posts like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/365061/high-load-average-low-cpu-usage-why/524818), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116849/why-load-is-high-despite-the-fact-that-neither-cpu-or-disk-is-overused) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134381/very-high-cpu-load-but-nothing-significant-in-top). But they mostly talk about some issues in network or disk, and my network & disk seems OK.

So what should I do? Or, is this even NOT a problem? Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: From what I know, the more calculating power your CPU has the more electricity it consumes, and with electricity comes heat, so CPU under intensive usage will generate a lot heat, if that heat isn't dissipated, then the temperature of your CPU will raise significantly, so I think heavy CPU usage will definitely shorten the CPU's lifespan.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς Hmm I am on a public cloud, so I do not care about the heat...